# Unable to push Go app inside cloud foundry

Tags: go, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to push Go app into cloud foundry. When I try to build the binary and push it the app crashes and it returns start unsuccessful.

This is my manifest file

```
---
applications:
- name: project-suspension
  instances: 1
  memory: 256MB
  disk_quota: 512MB
  buildpacks: 
  - go_buildpack
  - binary_buildpack
 env:
    GOPACKAGENAME: dev.azure.com/.../service-infrastructure
```

I tried putting every file inside the root folder of the project but the app is still crashing when I push it. The other thing i tried is using the command flag -c "project-suspension" and it still crashes.

Comment: Either use the go_buildpack and push your sources, or build the application locally and push the generated binary using the binary_buildpack.

Comment: I posted an answer fit for the info you've provided so far. If that doesn't help, or for future reference, make sure you get the output of `cf logs` and `cf events` for your app, so there's more information about what happens when the app "crashes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you don't need both buildpacks. Use either the go-buildpack, if you are pushing source code, or the binary buildpack if you are building locally and pushing the binary. If pushing a binary built locally, you need to cross-compile for Linux (unless you are running Linux as your workstation).

Ex:

```
---
applications:
- name: project-suspension
  instances: 1
  memory: 256MB
  disk_quota: 512MB
  buildpacks: 
  - go_buildpack
 env:
    GOPACKAGENAME: dev.azure.com/.../service-infrastructure
```

or

```
---
applications:
- name: project-suspension
  instances: 1
  memory: 256MB
  disk_quota: 512MB
  buildpacks: 
  - binary_buildpack
  command: ./project-suspension
```

The latter assumes that the binary you want to run is called `project-suspension` and that it exists in the same directory from which `cf push` is run (or the same directory where you've set `path:` or `-p`.

Also, be aware that applications can fail to start for other reasons, like if the health check does not pass. The default health check is going to be port-based, so it'll expect your application to be listening on the port number set with `$PORT`. Make sure your app reads `$PORT` and listens on that port.